# PyQt5: Using decorators with methods connected to signals

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots

I want to use a decorator to handle exceptions within a class. However, when using the decorator, it always gives me:

`TypeError: f1() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I am quite sure it occurs due to `self`, because it works perfectly outside the class. But I cannot manage to use it inside the class. Can someone help me?

Here is a MWE:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QWidget
import sys


def report_exceptions(f):
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"caught: {e}")   
    return wrapped_f


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        b1 = QPushButton('1')
        b1.clicked.connect(self.f1)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(b1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    @report_exceptions
    def f1(self):
        raise Exception("Error inside f1")


app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do you still get the same exception if you remove everything Qt related?

Comment: It works without Qt

Comment: Do you still get the same exception if you keep the Qt related stuff, but use a plain function? What exactly does "it works perfectly outside the class" mean? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. I suspect this MWE is not really M.

Comment: try to change signature of `f1` to allow extra args, set breakpoint inside function and analyze `args` and `kwargs` values (or just print them), you will quickly understand what is happening and why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because the [clicked signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) sends a default *checked* parameter which the `f1` method does not provide an argument for. There are several ways to work around this:

- change the signature to allow for the extra argument:

  ```
   def f1(self, checked=False):
  ```
- use a lambda to consume the unwanted argument:

  ```
   b1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.f1())
  ```
- wrap the method as a [pyqt slot](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator):

  ```
   @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
   @report_exceptions
   def f1(self):
  ```

The reason why this last one works is because signals with default arguments are treated as two separate overloads: one which which sends the parameter, and one which doesn't. The slot decorator therefore allows you to explicitly select which one is required (the other overload being `@QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)`).

Another peculiarity specific to PyQt is that signals connected to undecorated slots will normally ignore unused parameters. The lambda solution above takes advantage of this mechanism, but your `report_exceptions` decorator effectively bypasses it, which is why you get the TypeError.